# C3.js show tooltip from button click

Tags: javascript, css, c3

I am using C3.js to graph some data. I want to be able to show the tooltip for the last data point series from a button click or even by default once the chart has rendered. Is there anyway to do this? Their documentation has a section for tooltip.show but there is no documentation for it.

[missing documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-tooltip-show)

Comment: I was able to use google charts to do this using annotations, even though I like c3 better I couldnt find the solution using c3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpliest syntax is this:

```
chart.tooltip.show({x: 5});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kreozot/gr035uaj/2/)

Is this is what you want?

Comment: How do you make this work with time-series charts?